# How to use an api's URL inside an asp.net core controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core, url

So I need to create a C# API SMSController that sends an sms using the following URL api

https://[WEBSITELINK]/bestsmsbulkapi/sendSms.php?username=USERNAME&&password=PASSWORD&&message=MESSAGE&&senderid=SENDERID&&destination=DESTINATION

How can I do that?

Comment: You need yo provide more detail here. I would start by seeing what your endpoint needs to satisfy the request. Is it a `GET`, a `POST` ? 
After you do that I would suggest looking at a `HttpClient` to send that request.

 More specifically if you are using `.net core` I would suggest implementing an `HttpClient` with the `IHttpClientFactory` interface. See more about it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

you don't mentioned your api method accept get or post method..
below code is for get method, this may help you.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:60464/api/");
                //HTTP GET
                var responseTask = client.GetAsync("student");
                responseTask.Wait();

                var result = responseTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<Student[]>();
                    readTask.Wait();

                    var students = readTask.Result;

                    foreach (var student in students)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(student.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client